# TyperError When trying to show an image in grayscale on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I keep getting a TypeError: Invalid shape (825,) for image data when trying to display the image in grayscale.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import os
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16, 8]

A = mpimg.imread('image4.jpg')
X = np.mean(A, -1)

img = plt.imshow(X)
img.set_cmap('gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: There may be a problem with your image file. https://www.pygame.org/docs/_static/pygame_tiny.png. I converted to jpg and it worked with your code.

Comment: Thank you!! I ended up taking a screen shot of the original image and just renaming it and it worked perfectly.

Comment: What is `A.shape`?

Answer (score 0):

(Moving my comment to answer)

There may be a problem with your image file. I tested with pygame.org/docs/_static/pygame_tiny.png. I converted to jpg and it worked with your code.

[image: PyGame Image]